# What are the percentages of matter in the universe, and how did we find out?

Tags: space-telescope, galactic

What are the percentages of matter in the universe?
And how did we find out about it?

Comment: The universe is around 74% hydrogen, 24% helium and 1% oxygen, with stars slowly converting the hydrogen to helium, and a tiny amount of other stuff. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually really easy to find on the internet.
Try to google and research before posting a question, it saves time :).

68% dark energy
27% dark matter
5% ordinary matter

In 2015 the Planck satellite consortium released an analysis of data collected by the Planck satellite that showed this percentage break down of the universe’s mass/energy.

Ordinary matter: 4.9%

Dark Matter: 26.8%,

Dark Energy: 68.3%

Comment: I kind of want to ask the obvious follow-up, how did it do this? But I feel that's also Google-worthy :).

Comment: https://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Planck/Planck_at_a_glance Special delivery

Comment: it didn't do it @MagicOctopusUrn, it obtained some data that was plugged into an cosmological model of the universe, and the numbers came tumbling out.

Comment: @JCRM hehe... I guess I shouldve said how did the super computer that proceased the data connect the "dots".

Comment: I asked the question on astronomy. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29232/25592